# Write Values to Empty List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of names of unknown length. I want to write the names with their corresponding key (`name` to an empty list of dictionaries).

Input:

```
names = ['john', 'bill']
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'bill'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
names = ['john', 'bill']
dic = [{'name': name} for name in names]

print(dic)
#[{'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'bill'}]
```